# What is the dimension of span of a vector orthogonal to 'n' linearly independent vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matrix-rank, orthogonal-matrices

So let's say I have "*n*" linearly independent vectors in "*m*" dimensions `(m > n)`.
Is it true that the dimension of span of these *n* vectors is also n?
And if I find a vector orthogonal to all the *n* vectors, what will be the span of combined system of the *n* vectors and the orthogonal vector? *n+1*?
If yes, how can I prove it?

Comment: The dimension of a vecor space is the amount of vectors of any basis. If a finite number of l.i vectors spans a vector space, it is a base of this vector space.

Comment: @Johnathan The answer to all your yes/no questions is yes. As the other answer indicates, proving this comes down to the definition of dimension.